# How to allow multiple sign in in Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to enable multi sign-in for my spring security application i.e. For example, if I have two email addresses, I would want to allow the user to sign in with multiple email addresses and the user can shift from one email account to the other, just as [Gmail Multiple Sign-in](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1721977?hl=en). How could I do that with Spring security?

There seems to be only one `Principal` instead of list of principals in the Spring security. Could I achieve it?

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Thanks in advance. Hope you will reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent `Spring Security` supports user switch. It is more like a `su` under Linux.
Nevertheless, you can reuse some code from [`SwitchUserFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.html) to create your own user switch.

Primarily, you need to create

- Custom Spring Security [`UserDetails`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) which holds a list of usernames a switch is allowed to
- Custom [`UserDetailsService`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) which populates your custom UserDetails
- Custom UserSwitchFilter based on Spring's SwitchUserFilter

Custom `UserDetails` and `UserDetailsService` are just examples here and may differ from your own implementation. The idea is to hold a list of usernames in UserDetails for later processing in custom UserSwitchFilter.

CustomUserDetails:

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User {

    private final Set<String> linkedAccounts;

    public CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, Set<String> linkedAccounts, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.linkedAccounts = linkedAccounts;
    }

    public Set<String> getLinkedAccounts() {
        return linkedAccounts;
    }
}
```

CustomUserDetailsService:

```
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private UserDao userDao = ...;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        BackendUser user = userDao.findUserByUsername(username);        
        return new CustomUserDetails(user.getHane(), ......);
    }
}
```

Main differences to Spring Security UserSwitchFilter:

- Added method `checkSwitchAllowed` checks if a switch to that specific user from current authenticated user is allowed
- switch is based on query paramater and not url for better user experience (see `requiresSwitchUser`). hence `no need for switchUserUrl` and `targetUrl`
- Custom UserSwitchFilter ha no notion of a `exitUserUrl`. Hence no need for `exitUserUrl`
- `createSwitchUserToken` doesn't modify user authorities

CustomSwitchUserFilter:

```
public class CustomSwitchUserFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements  ApplicationEventPublisherAware, MessageSourceAware {

    public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_SWITCH_USERNAME_KEY = "j_switch_username";

    private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;
    private AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest, ?> authenticationDetailsSource = new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource();
    protected MessageSourceAccessor messages = SpringSecurityMessageSource.getAccessor();
    private String switchFailureUrl;
    private String usernameParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_SWITCH_USERNAME_KEY;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private UserDetailsChecker userDetailsChecker = new AccountStatusUserDetailsChecker();
    private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(userDetailsService, "userDetailsService must be specified");
        if (failureHandler == null) {
            failureHandler = switchFailureUrl == null ? new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler() :
                    new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(switchFailureUrl);
        } else {
            Assert.isNull(switchFailureUrl, "You cannot set both a switchFailureUrl and a failureHandler");
        }
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        // check for switch or exit request
        if (requiresSwitchUser(request)) {
            // if set, attempt switch and store original
            try {
                Authentication targetUser = attemptSwitchUser(request);

                // update the current context to the new target user
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(targetUser);
            } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
                logger.debug("Switch User failed", e);
                failureHandler.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, e);
                return;
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    protected Authentication attemptSwitchUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws AuthenticationException {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken targetUserRequest;

        String username = request.getParameter(usernameParameter);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Attempt to switch to user [" + username + "]");
        }

        UserDetails targetUser = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        userDetailsChecker.check(targetUser);

        checkSwitchAllowed(targetUser);

        // OK, create the switch user token
        targetUserRequest = createSwitchUserToken(request, targetUser);

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Switch User Token [" + targetUserRequest + "]");
        }

        // publish event
        if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new AuthenticationSwitchUserEvent(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), targetUser));
        }

        return targetUserRequest;
    }

    private void checkSwitchAllowed(UserDetails targetUser) {
        CustomUserDetails details = (CustomUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String targetUsername = targetUser.getUsername();

        //target username has to be in linked accounts otherwise this is an unauthorized switch
        if(!details.getLinkedAccounts().contains(targetUsername)) {
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException("user switch not allowed");
        }
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken createSwitchUserToken(HttpServletRequest request, UserDetails targetUser) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken targetUserRequest;

        // get the original authorities
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> orig = targetUser.getAuthorities();

        // add the new switch user authority
        List<GrantedAuthority> newAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(orig);

        // create the new authentication token
        targetUserRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(targetUser, targetUser.getPassword(), newAuths);

        // set details
        targetUserRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));

        return targetUserRequest;
    }

    protected boolean requiresSwitchUser(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
        return parameterMap.containsKey(usernameParameter);
    }

    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher)
            throws BeansException {
        this.eventPublisher = eventPublisher;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationDetailsSource(AuthenticationDetailsSource<HttpServletRequest,?> authenticationDetailsSource) {
        Assert.notNull(authenticationDetailsSource, "AuthenticationDetailsSource required");
        this.authenticationDetailsSource = authenticationDetailsSource;
    }

    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        Assert.notNull(messageSource, "messageSource cannot be null");
        this.messages = new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);
    }

    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    public void setSwitchFailureUrl(String switchFailureUrl) {
        Assert.isTrue(StringUtils.hasText(usernameParameter) && UrlUtils.isValidRedirectUrl(switchFailureUrl),
                "switchFailureUrl cannot be empty and must be a valid redirect URL");
        this.switchFailureUrl = switchFailureUrl;
    }

    public void setFailureHandler(AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler) {
        Assert.notNull(failureHandler, "failureHandler cannot be null");
        this.failureHandler = failureHandler;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsChecker(UserDetailsChecker userDetailsChecker) {
        this.userDetailsChecker = userDetailsChecker;
    }

    public void setUsernameParameter(String usernameParameter) {
        this.usernameParameter = usernameParameter;
    }
}
```

Add `CustomSwitchUserFilter` to your security filter chain. It has to be placed after `FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR`.

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isFullyAuthenticated()" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.do" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.do" />
    <security:custom-filter ref="switchUserProcessingFilter" after="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
</security:http>

<bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="security.CustomSwitchUserFilter">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
</bean>
```

You can find a working example [here](https://github.com/ksokol/spring-sandbox/tree/user-switch).